# The Excel table below gives THE details on THE calculations for THE results

Tags: articles

In the sentence

"The Excel table below gives THE details on THE calculations for THE results"

Which THE is necessary, and which ones are not?
I'm basically trying to say: the Excel table contains detailed breakdowns of the calculations. Those calculations provided me with the results.

The sentence somehow sounds clumsy and I am not sure if all the THEs are necessary, and whether all the nouns need to be in plural forms.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can certainly omit the second "the". *It gives details of...*

Comment: After the question edit: *The Excel table contains a detailed breakdown of the calculations.* The second sentence is unnecessary because it repeats what the first sentence says. Note that *breakdown* is singular when used for analysis. It is used in the plural for vehicle breakdowns.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. The second paragraph in my question is just to explain in detail what I was trying to express in the first sentence.

Comment: Well, the phrasing in the second paragraph is more natural and fluent. My version doesn't even mention *results* - that is was the Excel table is *for*, so it's not necessary to explain that.

Comment: Your explanation of what you're trying to say is the easiest way to say it: "The Excel table contains detailed breakdowns of the calculations...", and you can add "...of the results".